# How do I get my button to jump to the top of the page using a C# method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, blazor

I am using C# to create a method called `GoToNextStep` which will take the user to the next page of the form on click.  The method currently looks like this:

Wizard.cs File

```
public void GoToNextStep()
    {


        Step += 1;            
        Progress += .2;
        if (Step == 6)
        {
            Progress = 100;
        }
        SetNavButtons();
    }
```

Form.razor File

```
<div id="form-navigation-container">
   @if (@Wizard.Step != 1)
   {
       <MatButton Class="previous" disabled="@Wizard.PreviousButtonDisabled" @onclick="Wizard.GoToPreviousStep">Previous Step</MatButton>
   }

   @if (@Wizard.Step != 5)
   {
       <MatButton Unelevated="true" disabled="@Wizard.NextButtonDisabled" @onclick="Wizard.GoToNextStep">Next Step</MatButton>
   }
</div>
```

I have tried looking around for help regarding C# jump links but was not able to find anything.  Please note that I am very new to C# and would appreciate an explanation of any and all answers.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: This one is problem more advanced than what you're trying to do, but if you are trying to create a wizard form with each page or modal to do something different, please refer to the link below:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-wizard-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-1/

Comment: You can do it with a [JS interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0)